# Load Images in map function dynamic

Tags: reactjs

I want to laod images in a mpa dynamic.
For that i have the following code in my render method:

```
const liste = this.state.expatListe.map((expat,index) =>
<Col md={1} xs={12} className="karten" key={index} >
  <span className="KarteVorNachname">
  <img src="https://www.countryflags.io/${expat.Code}/flat/64.png"/>
  <h5 className="kuerzen">{expat.First_Name}</h5>
  <h2 className="kuerzen">{expat.Last_Name}</h2>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
         <EmailIcon style={{ fontSize: 30,margin:"10px" }}  />
         <DeleteForeverIcon  style={{ fontSize: 30,margin:"10px" }} />
         <DeleteForeverIcon  style={{ fontSize: 30,margin:"10px" }} />
       </Grid>
    <h5>{expat.Comments}</h5>
</span>
</Col>
```

So the Image should load the src with the value from the map. 
So how could i do that ?

${} only works on strings defined with back ticks (``) try;

`source={'https://www.countryflags.io/${expat.Code}/flat/64.png'}` with backticks

Comment: You should use something like this: **{`https://iheartdogs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/${this.props.dogName}`**

Comment: @-Hosar No working

Comment: Not ,my code looks so  <img src={'https://www.countryflags.io/${expat.Code}/flat/64.png'}/> But nothing worked

Comment: You should use JS template string `template_is_here` as Medet suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src={`https://www.countryflags.io/${expat.Code}/flat/64.png`}/>
```

Just use curly bracers